# Why am I getting "validation failed" error?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a basic `expressjs` application. When I am trying to make a `POST` request I am always getting error, which says: `"User validation failed: name: Path "name" is required., email: Path "email" is required., password: Path "password" is required."`

My request(json):

```
[
   {
      "name":"test",
      "email":"test@gmail.com",
      "password":"testtest"
   }
]
```

Controller:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  service.saveUser(req, res);
});
```

Service (I think something here should be wrong):

```
const saveUser = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const newUser = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });
  const savedUser = newUser.save();
  res.json(savedUser);
};
```

And finally the `User` mode:

```
const Model = db.Schema({
  id: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You request

```
[
   {
      "name":"test",
      "email":"test@gmail.com",
      "password":"testtest"
   }
]
```

but you should instead request

```
{
   "name":"test",
   "email":"test@gmail.com",
   "password":"testtest"
}
```